# JSF 2 , noSelectionOption with Converter , Not working as it should

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters, selectonemenu

I'm Migrating My project from **seam 2** to **JSF 2.x** .

In **seam 2** for enum's we have

```
<s:convertEnum />
```

which will call the converter when correct value is selected not the noSelectionOption value.

In **JSF 2.x** I have created My custom Converter like

```
@Named("enumConverter")
@ApplicationScoped
public class EnumConverter implements Converter {

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String key) 
        throws ConverterException {
if(!key.equalsIgnoreCase("-- Choose one --")){
    // DO LOGIC
}
return null;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
}
```

Now the problem is in my view I'm using 
the converter like

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.DocumentType}" required="true">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Choose one --" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
        <f:selectItems value="${user.Constants(user.statuses)}"
            var="Val" itemLabel="#{user.Display(Val)}" 
        />
        <f:converter converterId="enumConverter"></f:converter> 
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Here if i select the **NoSelectionOption** then also my converter is getting called ,,, which should not happen and it should be called only if correct value is needed

in case of seam 2 converter only if correct value is selected then only converter will be called otherwise **"value is required"** is displayed.

Kindly please tell me ,what I'm missing here ....
Appreciate and help ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was due to a4j:commandlink which was having reRender attribute , i replaced it with render attribute and now message is getting displayed.

***But now the issue is***

*if **required=true** is not there and i select **noSelectionOption** then it will store blank value in DB.
is it **necessary** to provide a **validator** in **jsf 2** for **noSelectionOption** ????

Thanks